# Material theme backwards compatibility

Tags: android, android-compatibility, android-support-library, material-design

From the [official doc](http://developer.android.com/preview/material/compatibility.html) I learned that it's not yet possible to create Material design apps
for older APIs. Does anyone know whether it will ever be possible to have the same Material look on all devices? Links would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: probably, when the **support library** will be updated.

Comment: Marked as a duplicate as it's the same question regarding Material theme backward compatibility. You can update that question with your detail if different.